# TypeError: n is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress site that has the following bit of JS:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
    console.log('Everything loaded');
    $('.slides').fadeIn();
});
```

I'm seeing "Everything loaded" in the console, but the following line causes an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n is not a function
```

I don't understand what's causing the problem. The JS file has jQuery as a dependency, and there are other jQuery functions that are working fine. It's just the above section that's causing an error.

---

Here's a screenshot from the console, because some people are having difficulty believing the above code is causing the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: With provided code: I don't believe that it would through `n is not a function`. Please post relevant code that throw this error.

Comment: Seems like you have `jQuery` as alias of `$`... try: `jQuery('.slides').fadeIn();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is because you have set the event parameter as provided to the handler function with the name of `$`. This overwrites the jQuery instance of `$`, hence the error. You just need to remove the `$` from the function parameters:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { // < remove the $ here
    console.log('Everything loaded');
    jQuery('.slides').fadeIn();
});
```

Note that from your comments you're looking to alias the `jQuery` variable as a `$` after using `noConflict()`. To do this you can use this signature `document.ready` handler:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        console.log('Everything loaded');
        $('.slides').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe it as I was using (in many projects) $ inside function wrapper to avoid jquery conflict. How could this be the problem?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt It sounds like you should use `jQuery` instead of `$` inside the function then, see my update.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal it's not a conflict, it's changing the value of the `$` variable within the scope of the function due to the mis-named parameter.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, that works of course, but I don't understand why using an alias wasn't working...?

Comment: It's because the parameter provided to a function is an `event`, not an instance of jQuery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah. That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I updated my answer to make the distinction clearer.

Answer (score -2):

//try below code (remove $ )

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  console.log('Everything loaded');
  $('.slides').fadeIn();
});
```